# New SQL column, with repeating value when new row created?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to create an SQL column on a database with the following rule:

**On each new row in this specific column, default value is the integer "1".**

I know how to use null/not null,

```
ALTER TABLE {TABLENAME} 
ADD {COLUMNNAME} {TYPE} {NULL|NOT NULL} 
CONSTRAINT {CONSTRAINT_NAME} DEFAULT {DEFAULT_VALUE}
```

But i'm stumped as to how i could get the row to have a default integer, i'm not experienced in SQL and don't know what to search for!

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server? They are not the same thing.

Comment: I am using MySQL, sorry the tag was auto-suggested and i didn't realize they were different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply fill in:

```
ALTER TABLE your_table 
ADD your_column INTEGER NOT NULL
DEFAULT 1;
```

Comment: what's the difference between using "INTEGER NOT NULL" and JChao's shorter version?

Comment: @ThatGuy343 `NOT NULL` means that the column must have a value. Otherwise it also can contain `NULL` which is interpreted as no value (has a special behaviour at comparing and calculations).

Answer (score 1):

```
   ALTER TABLE table1 ADD COLUMN someColName INT DEFAULT 1;
```